# "I would like it if you did not do that" -- why "did"?

Tags: grammar

> I would like it if you did not do that.

In context, you *are* doing that, and I'd like you stop.

Why "did" instead of "do"?  I think that it is the [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood), but I am not certain.

Would it make a difference if you were just considering doing that and I am trying to talk you out of i?

Comment: It's because ***would*** here implies a *counterfactual* statement. Being precise, the speaker doesn't explicitly say he *does* like it, only that he *would* (if some unspecified circumstance arose, which might or might not be "you not doing it"). Since counterfactual things aren't happening in the here and now, the speaker uses the "not present" tense (it doesn't imply "past" in this context).

Comment: It would sound strange if there were two 'woulds' in the same sentence, i.e. 'I would like it if you would not do that'. A way to avoid this is by contracting the first would: "I'd like it if you wouldn't do that"

Comment: @V0ight -- if we are just considering euphony, people say, "I would like it if you would stop" all the time (uh, not to me, of course).  Do you think that sound grating?

Comment: @Malvolio ~ good point, replacing 'not do that' with 'stop' does seem to make it easier on the ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  The sentence is using the subjunctive mood.  The conjugation of the subjunctive mood for the verb "to do" is "did" — not to be confused with the preterit, which is also "did."  Sometimes such sentences become clearer examples of the subjunctive mood when you look at them uninverted, for example:

- If you did not do that, I would like it.

Another way to word it would be as follows:

- I would like it if you were to not do that.

To more aptly demonstrate the subjunctive mood in contrast to the preterit, a better example would use the first person singular rather than the second person, as follows:

- You would like it if I *were* to not do that.

You'll notice that the verb after "I" isn't "was."  The first and third person singular conjugations of the verb "to be" are the only instances where the subjunctive mood doesn't exactly mimic the preterit tense in the words it applies.

Comment: Whoever said that the three sweetest words in the English language are "I love you" obviously never considered the appeal of "You are right."