# Use of -s at the end of verb when using ”would”?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, conditionals, inflectional-morphology

I want to know how the *-s* is supposed to be used with *she/he/it* + *would*.

While trying to say that it would be great for someone/something to allow something, I came up with this sentence, which I think is incorrect:

> It would be fantastic **if the teacher *allows** us do certain action.

But...

> It would be fantastic **if the teacher allow** us do certain action.

doesn’t seem right to me either, so what would be the proper way to say that someone or something *would* (potential) + some verb inflected with that verb’s third-personal singular *-s* present-tense inflection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I would like it if you did not do that" -- why "did"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337227/i-would-like-it-if-you-did-not-do-that-why-did)

Comment: Both sentences are correct. However, they mean different things and would never be used in the same contexts.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't understand how can they both be right nor how can they mean different things. Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: @sumelic I edited my question, could you please let me know what you think about that?

Comment: Thanks, that edit does help. No one would say "if the teacher allow us." It is possible to use "it would be fantastic if the teacher allowed us..."

Comment: Thanks for the advice @choster ; my user name is because of my stackoverflow account, you could say I'm a newbie in programming, and the accounts are linked because of using the same e-mail :) I'm not a newbie at english at all, but of course I'm so benefit from this type of answers with great stuff to read. Thanks. Great answer BTW.

Comment: Great edit @Laurel ! thanks, I think the answers will be more useful to people who might have the same question in the future.

Comment: I take it back. Either I thought I saw something different or #2 has been edited.  *_It would be fantastic if the teacher allow us to do certain things_ is **not** grammatical. But _It would be fantastic if the teacher allowed us to do certain things_ is grammatical, and means something different from #1.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes, it has been changed. It used to be "let"; I recommended changing it because of the ambiguous conjugation of that verb.

Comment: @newbie: I've currently voted to close because this question is about a very complex topic that is amply covered in resources for English language learners: how to form conditionals. Here is a handout you might find helpful: http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/conditionals-verb-tense-in-if-clauses/.

Comment: Also a related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306310/conditional-tenses. I don't think the concept of "subjunctive" that other posters have mentioned is very useful at all if you're just trying to understand how to use these sentences properly. The form that you use after "if" will almost always be the same as either a regular past or a regular present-tense form; there is no common pattern of dropping the "-s" off of third-person present-tense verbs after "if".

Comment: I agree. Calling it subjunctive is just handwaving. That answer is certainly not a "duplicate". Though I disagree about closing the question, at least in its original form; I was debating answering that. But I haven't followed the argument here and now it's changed so I doubt it.

Comment: @sumelic I'm not an expert in english, it's actually my second lenguage, but I can definitly tell when something doesn't sound right to me and wasn't really contemplating the possibility of another type of mistake, don't worry about the use of `s` here, I will probably realise if I'm using it wrong even when there's no pattern for it. Probably this should be closed, because it was actually a verbe tense mistake and not one related to what I actually thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mis-analysing. The "would" is in a different clause, and has absolutely no effect on the form of the verb in the conditional clause "if the teacher allows us ... ".

When a modal like "would" is followed by a verb *in the same clause* then the verb is in base form ("He would allow us ..."), but that is an entirely different case.

On a different topic, *allow* requires an infinitive clause with "to", so "allows us **to** do certain actions" is needed.

Comment: Kind of misses the essential point that a past form is needed here because this is a remote conditional construction.

Comment: True. I was answering the direct question, and missed that.